# Https with custom domain in Heroku

Tags: http, ssl, heroku, https

Hi I recently learned that Heroku has piggyback SSL. However when I configured my site to a custom domain, suddenly it only goes to http. Changing the forwarding in my domain manager (GoDaddy) to Https does not work. However the default url of Heroku goes to https. Is there a way to configure my domain in such a way to make use of the piggyback SSL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku provides SSL by default on all *.herokuapp.com domains - they also have free SSL available for paid apps using SNI based SSL and LetsEncrypt. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management for info that. You can't change a default URL, you'd have to handle the redirect in your application to force SSL.